# 2 computed properties based on the same dependency fire only once

Tags: ember.js

Having 2 computed properties based on the same dependency only one computed property runs. The docs says that it is cached what about a situation when I'd like to have the following:

```
  foo: (->
    console.log 'foo'
  ).property('dependency')

  bar: (->
    console.log 'bar'
  ).property('dependency')
```

Now the `bar` isn't called and I have to resort to observer. Can I make it work?

---

### Edit

The question is about computed properties but it wasn't reflected in the example code - instead of `property` I used `observes`. It is now changed. Sorry for confusion.

---

### Edit#2

I modified the great example by @MilkyWayJoe so that it now looks like my solution. Unfortunately (or fortunately) it works, but my solution didn't. Here's the gist what I was after:

With the help of a slider I could set a balance value to be transferred to another credit card provider. Let's say that the value is `transferValue`. Whenever it changed I had to calculate the annual interest to which the transfer fee was added.

So for example let's say that in my current credit card I have $1000 and the annual interest rate is 19%. It's way too much so I look for another, cheaper solution. It turns out that Bank X offers Balance Transfer Credit Card Y which interest rate is 10% + 3.5% transfer fee.

OK. So I set $1000 on the slider and here goes the magic. I want to calculate interest rate and transfer fee whenever the value changes.

In the modified example it works: http://jsfiddle.net/gqSMU/2/
but failed to do so in my first solution. It was kind of this one:

```
cardInterest: (->
    apr = @get 'purchaseRate'
    amount = @get 'transferValue'
    @get('calculatedTransferFee') + @calculateInterest apr, amount
  ).property('transferValue', 'calculatedTransferFee')
```

As you can see it accesses `calculatedTransferFee`. The problem was that the value wasn't recalculated. I'm not sure it is worth of mentioning but in the first solution only `cardInterest` was requested by Handlebars template.

And this is my current solution with observer:

```
calculatedTransferFee: 0
  transferValueDidChange: (->
    if @get('isCurrentCardChosen')
      transferFee = parseFloat @get('balanceTransferRate') / 100
      transferValue = @get 'transferValue'
      calculatedTransferFee = if isNaN(transferFee) then 0 else transferFee * transferValue
      @set 'calculatedTransferFee', calculatedTransferFee
  ).observes('transferValue')
```

It isn't a nice solution, is it? That's why I thought it may be a better solution than to resort to an observer.

I hope that now it is clearer. I'd be grateful for any further feedback!

Comment: Can you provide a (not) working example? And are you sure that your two computed properties are being requested(with get on js or on template)? If it isn't called it will never be calculated.

Comment: @RenanTomalFernandes that's very interesting. Only the first, `foo` was requested in a template - the other one, `bar`, was not but I needed it in `foo` - it was requested via @get 'foo'. But as I said, because of cached `dependency` it wasn't fired.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if I understand what you're trying to achieve since you're talking about `property` but your code is using `observes` (I realize this is a conceptual sample code, just not sure where you're going).

Usually, `property` will be a "reactive accessor" to a value, and 99.9% of the time you want it to be cached (it is by default, unless you say `.property('whatever').volatile()`), while `observe` will fire a function when whatever property it is watching changes. If you just want to have two properties firing for the same dependency you could:

```
App.SomeModel = Em.Object.extend({
    someDependency: true,
    foo: function() {
        // all that's in here will fire only once when 'dependency' changes, and store
        // the returning value in cache, and every time something reads this property, 
        // it will retrieve the cached value. 
        // A way to test this, is to run the following from your View: 
        // "alert(this.controller.get('content.foo'));"
        // It will alert the string but will not log "whatever bro" again. 
        console.log('whatever bro'); 
        return "this.foo %@ a dependency".fmt(this.get('someDependency') ? "has" : "doesn't have");
    }.property('someDependency'),
    bar: function() {
        // same as above
        console.log('whatever dude'); 
        return "this.bar %@ a dependency".fmt(this.get('someDependency') ? "has" : "doesn't have");

    }.property('someDependency'),
    nope: function() {
        // same as above, except this is volatile 
        // and will fire the console.log every time
        console.log('y\'all need science'); 
        return "this.nope %@ a dependency".fmt(this.get('someDependency') ? "has" : "doesn't have");

    }.property('someDependency').volatile() 
});
```

(see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/upTd6/))

If you need it to be logged everytime (perhaps for debugging or whatever reason), you could use `volatile` or `observes`.

If I'm tripping and this's not what you want, perhaps you could rephrase your question or refresh the sample code to something closer to your real-life scenario to clarify what's being asked.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed example! I tried to modify it to the extent that it is similar to a real solution but I wasn't successful. Please take a look at the updated question for more information.

Comment: @WojtekRyrych I didn't see this comment before. I'll check this later today